# How to obtain the non-parsed angular expression passed as attribute to a directive?

Tags: angularjs, interpolation, directive

This is using angular 1.4.8.

I need to pass an HTML string that contains an angular expression to a directive using its attributes. The expression gets parsed and I only get the resulting string:

```
    <dynamic-template tpl = "selected: {{selection}}"/>
```

See below the "breakpoint here" comment. Arriving there, I need to have the angular expression (containing {{}}) and not the resulting string.

```
angular.module("sandbox").directive('dynamic-template', [function() {
        return {
            'replace'       : true,
            'transclude'    : true,             
            'bindToController'  : true,

            'compile': function (tElement, tAttrs) {
                return {
                    pre: function preLink(scope, element, attrs, controller){
                        controller.tpl = attrs.tpl; // breakpoint here
                    },

                    post: function (scope, element, attrs, controller){
                        controller.element = element;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

This to be able to $interpolate the display value on the fly based on a custom expression.
How can that be achieved? I expected that inspecting the attribute value in the pre compile would help. It still provides the interpolated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your things done in the compileFunction, there is nothing interpolated and u get the selected: {{selection}} string:

```
angular.module("sandbox").directive('dynamic-template', [function() {
    return {
        'replace'       : true,
        'transclude'    : true,
        'bindToController'  : true,
        'compile': CompileFunction
    };

    function CompileFunction(element, attrs) {
        // attrs.tpl
        return PostLinkFunction;
    }

    function PostLinkFunction(scope, element, attrs) {
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: Right, I was mistaken with using the pre-compile for that purpose. Good job!